# Breakpoint not getting hit in managed code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, managed, breakpoints

I am using Visual Studio 2010 & .NET Framework 3.5.

In my solution, I have a C++ project and a C# project. The C++ code in the former project invokes the managed code in the latter via (reverse) COM Interop. Both the dlls would get loaded into an external application. Both the projects are configured to start the same application when debugging is started.

**Problem:**
While debugging native code, the breakpoints are hit; however, while i want to debug the managed code, the breakpoints never get hit. This is the behavior regardless of the whether i start the application from native project or managed project.

**Options Tried:**

1. Setting the Debugger Type option in Native project properties to Mixed / Managed Only. Either case doesn't help.
2. Enabling / Disabling 'Enable Unmanaged code debugging' in Managed project properties also does not help.

Comment: Does this work in VS2008? I always get some error about mixed mode debugging not support for .NET 2/3.5 under VS2010. Have you tried targetting .NET 4 as a test?

Comment: These scenarios are explicitly supported.  There isn't anything in the question that allows anyone to guess why it doesn't work for you.  Could be as simple as the native code just not loading the managed code properly.